# taking an input img type selected picture and load into an image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, image

So, i have an input box for doing a img file upload.  What i was wanting to do is take the data from that (or the selected source) and route that into the src attribute of an image tag.

something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/QC2c4/

It is sort of going to be a client side verifier to show what the user is going to upload.  I know that i am going to need to check the extension for the valid img types, .png, .bmp, .png, .tiff, etc, etc.

How would i go about the linking process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the answer, and as an added bonus I loaded the image into the preview pane for ya. The key is pulling the `files[0]` object from the file picker on change.

http://jsfiddle.net/TbZzH/1/

Comment: i believe the proper phrase for your expeditiousness is...  like a boss.

Comment: That works with an anonymous function.  How would i make it work with a defined function?  What i mean is, instead of function(){...}   something like function test (){...}  and then $tag.on("change", test());   I was thinking about this, because i want to reuse it over and over, and not apply a 1 time instance to a button.  I tried to rip out the content and place into the function, but it seems like "this" no longer applies.   should i do something like:

.on("change",test(this));  and then function test(input){...}   ?

Sidenote:   I dont think that method works atm either.

Comment: Or, can you tell me what this refers to, so that I can wire it myself.

Comment: Oh hey, sorry I don't come back to SO as often as I should. I updated the example to do what you were asking about - let me know if anything is confusing about this! For me it's most elegant to extend jquery to add this method, but it can be done with a straight function too by passing the jquery object as an argument. http://jsfiddle.net/TbZzH/8/ - make sure you understand what's going on here before trying to implement it though!