# IE does not like my input and image tags

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer, input

My Code:

```
var data = $(input)[0];
var file = data.files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function (e) {
  value = e.target.result;
  try {
   top.document.getElementById('formDesignContents').contentWindow.updateFormFromToolbar(CURRENT_ATTRIBUTE, value, opts);
  } catch (err) {
     alert("error connecting to formDesignContents iframe from the toolbar");
  }
}
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

It works in GoogleChrome but not IE.  For IE, it does not recognize the attribute files under the input element.  The jquery is to dereference a jquery object back into standard html element.

Is there another way to accomplish for IE to work?  I can easily do one of those

```
if(IE){...}else{...}
```

blocks of code.  I just dont see why it doesnt recognize those items.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Answer (score 1):

IE doesn't support `FileReader`, so I'd expect your script to crash on this line:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
```

Unless you are using IE10?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I am using IE9, so that is an issue, yes.  data.files[0]; is the current spot where it seems to crash.  So i need to fix and adjust one before the other.  

The data.files[0] is said to be null or undefined.  I didnt think that was a part of the FileReader Class.  Thoughts on that one?  Are the issues related?

Comment: I inspected the element and it showed all the attributes, but it wasnt working so i printed out the Object.keys(data).toString() and it doesnt show anything after the first entry:

jQuery17208587565923765934

Even though it isn NOT any longer a jquery object.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your original explanation of the problem so I just pointed out what seemed the obvious issue. What do you get if you insert `console.dir(data)` before `var file = data.files[0];`? And should your first line use `$("input")` with quotes rather than `$(input)`? I'm not familiar with the `files` attribute of an `input` element.

Comment: nn, it says that console.dir(data); returns undefined where you wanted me to place it.  The input is correct as with quotes defines a new object of that type, where as i can import a jquery object into it like i have done.  I was sort of unsure as to the files attribute as well.  See, what my goal to do was to great a browe function which will take an image, and then put it on the client side of my program, in an image tag.  Ill post to my other stackoverflow question so you can see what i am trying to do.  The answer i got was right, it just doesnt work for IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159969/input-type-file-not-properly-putting-image-into-image-tag

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146874/taking-an-input-img-type-selected-picture-and-load-into-an-image-tag